# Calculation of the variance of an expression composed of RVs with standard normal distribution

Tags: self-study, variance

As part of a larger expression, I need to calculate $Var(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\epsilon_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2})$ where all the $x_i's$ and $\epsilon_i's$ are iid N(0.1). I'm stuck here. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you are to derive the *conditional* variance of the OLS estimator. So are you maybe asked to derive the variance of that ratio *conditional on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$*?

Comment: @ChristophHanck The larger problem I referred to is finding the variance of the MLE for a parameter $\theta$. There was no mention of the variables involved being conditional on the $x_i's$. Assuming there are none, and the only given is limited to that provided, what would be a good step forward in solving this?